# Оптимизировать и минимизировать скрипт

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Код рабочий, но мне кажется что его можно оптимизировать и минимизировать скрипт.
Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать и минимизировать.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var cookieName = 'level';
            var cookieOptions = {expires: 7, path: '/'};
            var kirov = '#kirov';
            var syiktyivkar = '#syiktyivkar';
            var syihtml='<i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Сыктывкар';
            var kirhtml='<i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Киров';
            var allhtml='<i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?=$CityIP[city];?>';
            $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass("selected");
            $("#kirov-map").click(function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#verbose").val("Cookie value is " + $.cookie(cookieName) + ".");
            });
            $("#kirov-map").click(function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#verbose").val("Cookie value is " + $.cookie(cookieName) + ".");
            });
            $("#header-top-logo a").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).removeClass("selected");
                $.cookie(cookieName, $(this).attr("id"), cookieOptions);
                $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass("selected");
            }); 

            if(!($('#kirov-map').hasClass('selected') || $('#syiktyivkar-map').hasClass('selected'))){
                if('<?=$CityIP[city];?>'=='Сыктывкар'){
                    $(kirov).collapse('hide');
                    $(syiktyivkar).collapse('show');
                    $('#button-city').html(syihtml);
                    $('#map-contact-bottom').addClass('active');
                    $('#map-contact-top').removeClass('active');
                }else{
                    $(kirov).collapse('show');
                    $(syiktyivkar).collapse('hide');
                    $('#button-city').html(kirhtml);
                    $('#map-contact-top').addClass('active');
                    $('#map-contact-bottom').removeClass('active');
                }
            }   

            $("#header-top-logo a").click(function(){
                if($('#syiktyivkar-map').hasClass('selected')){
                    $(kirov).collapse('hide');
                    $(syiktyivkar).collapse('show');
                    $('#button-city').html(syihtml);
                    $('#map-contact-bottom').addClass('active');
                    $('#map-contact-top').removeClass('active');
                }else if($('#kirov-map').hasClass('selected')){
                    $(kirov).collapse('show');
                    $(syiktyivkar).collapse('hide');
                    $('#button-city').html(kirhtml);
                    $('#map-contact-top').addClass('active');
                    $('#map-contact-bottom').removeClass('active');
                }else{
                    $(kirov).collapse('show');
                    $(syiktyivkar).collapse('hide');
                    $('#button-city').html(allhtml);
                    $('#map-contact-top').addClass('active');
                    $('#map-contact-bottom').removeClass('active');
                }
            });

            if($('#syiktyivkar-map').hasClass('selected')){
                $(kirov).collapse('hide');
                $(syiktyivkar).collapse('show');
                $('#button-city').html(syihtml);
                $('#map-contact-bottom').addClass('active');
                $('#map-contact-top').removeClass('active');
            }else if($('#kirov-map').hasClass('selected')){
                $(kirov).collapse('show');
                $(syiktyivkar).collapse('hide');
                $('#button-city').html(kirhtml);
                $('#map-contact-top').addClass('active');
                $('#map-contact-bottom').removeClass('active');
            }else{
                $(kirov).collapse('show');
                $(syiktyivkar).collapse('hide');
                $('#button-city').html(allhtml);
                $('#map-contact-top').addClass('active');
                $('#map-contact-bottom').removeClass('active');
            }
            $(kirov).on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
                $(syiktyivkar).collapse('hide');
                $('#map-contact-top').addClass('active');
                $('#map-contact-bottom').removeClass('active');
            });
            $(syiktyivkar).on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
                $(kirov).collapse('hide');
                $('#map-contact-bottom').addClass('active');
                $('#map-contact-top').removeClass('active');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Ознакомься с [требованиями](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review) к вопросам по инспекции кода и приведи свой вопрос в соответствие им.

Comment: Другими словами напишите ЧТО хотели сделать чтобы мы могли подсказать КАК это сделать лучше. Понятно что при желании и по коду можно попробовать догадаться, но большинству очень неохота